# Programmatic Step Control in Gazebo Classic

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-11

I cannot find any resources explaining how to programmatically step through a running instance of Gazebo Classic. I would like to able to specify e.g. "run the simulation for 5ms and the pause again".

Is this possible, even via a Transport message perhaps?

The only alternative I can think of is to implement my own plugin for this functionality.

Thanks